# Move row entry up by one depending on value in column to the left

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I would like to know how to move a row entry up or down in sql server depending on the value on the column to its left. For instance, this is my table:

```
nodetype localname text
1        events    NULL
1        event     NULL
2        id        NULL
3        #text     21515 
2        side      NULL
3        #text     Away
2        type      NULL
3        #text     Goal 
1        result    NULL
3        #text     <b>Robin Van Persie</b>Goal
```

Anything with #text from column 'localname' I wish to move the row entry from column 'text' up by one. So 'id' corresponds to 21515, 'side' = Away, 'type' = Goal and 'result' = **Robin Van Persie** Goal . I'm not sure of the query to modify the table...

Comment: It looks like you are asking the wrong question - the source data for this table looks like it has the structure needed to solve this question much more directly. Could you add more context?

Comment: I have used openrowset to query an xml and import it into an sql serer table. The xml has a timeline of a soccer match, and each entry has an event description. This is how it's laid out:

- <events>
- <event id="21536609" clock="24" side="away" type="yellowCard" addedTime="" videoId="">
- <result>
- <![CDATA[ <b>Michael Dawson</b> - 24'<br>Yellow Card
  ]]> 
  </result>
  </event>
</events>

Comment: So you want: `id = 21515; side = Away; type = Goal; result = <b>Robin Van Persie</b>Goal`?

Comment: That would be good yea, sorry I didn't provide the same example from the xml!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get further if you reshape the incoming data. Here's an example based on the data you gave me:

```
/* setup storage for xml data */
declare @r table(data xml)

/* get xml data, either from string or file */
insert into @r
select cast('<events><event id="21536609" clock="24" side="away" type="yellowCard" addedTime="" videoId=""><result><![CDATA[ <b>Michael Dawson</b> - 24''<br>Yellow Card ]]> </result> </event> </events>' as xml)
--select CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) data from openrowset(Bulk 'd:\temp\f.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) [rowsetresults]

/* for each 'event' element in the source, pull out the attribute values and the first result */
select *
from (
select e.value('./@id', 'bigint') id, 
    e.value('./@clock', 'int') clock,
    e.value('./@side', 'nvarchar(100)') side,
    e.value('./@type', 'nvarchar(100)') type,
    e.value('(./result/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') result
from (select * from @r) t
cross apply t.data.nodes('/events/event') as t2(e)
) events
```

Note that you get the values in columnar form vs. row form (e.g. key/value pair like your question shows). This is easy to pivot to row form, but also columnar form is usually preferred in SQL scenarios.

Also note this only pulls out the first result in each event. To pull out all results, you'd have to `cross apply` at the `result` element level.